# Failed: null value in entry: name=null error while switching Popup window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to switch popup window of my AngularJS application. Following is my code:

```
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

    });
```

Getting following error:

```
Failed: null value in entry: name=null
Stack:
UnknownError: null value in entry: name=null
```

Comment: This happens when handles[1] doesn't exist. You maybe trying to switch to the new tab before it loads.

Comment: The problem might occur in Chrome. When you launch popups with Protractor, you need to name those windows accordingly, otherwise, they get a name of "null" and you will not be able to switch to that popup.

Comment: Hi Adrian : could u please share example how we can do that .

Answer (score 5):

You might be *trying to switch to a new tab before it is actually opened* - wait for the window handles count to be more than a desired count with a custom Expected Condition:

```
function windowCount(count) {
    return function () {
        return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            return handles.length >= count;
        });
    };
};
browser.wait(windowCount(2), 10000);

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
});
```

Comment: No luck alexce : i am getting error for wait timeout

Comment: @AbbasALI at least this gives us some more information that a new window is not actually opening..could you see the same problem in firefox and in chrome? Thanks.

Comment: @alexce : I could see popup window open . I put browser.sleep to check it but not getting handle

Comment: @alexce: I found that in angular js application popup window should be identified by its model id  . we cannot find handle for dialogue box

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS application there is not handle for popup window ,we need to get model Id for popup and then need to identify elements on it

eg .

var alertPop = element(by.id('popId'))

expect(alertPop.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

var element= alertPop.element(by.model('vm.message'));