# Focusing on angular4 popup window with Protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm unable to get my UI test to focus on a popup window. At this stage, I'd be happy to simply click `PayBill`, wait for the popup window (which loads instantly), then click `Cancel`.

The latest version of my code reads:

```
paybillButton.click();
browser.sleep(500);

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  newWindowHandle = handles[1];
  browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function () {
    cancelButton.click();
  });
});
```

But it keeps failing between `browser.switchTo()` and `.window(newWindowHandle).then ...`

Error:

```
Failed: null value in entry: handle=null
WebDriverError: null value in entry: handle=null
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.switchTo().window(undefined)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
    at TargetLocator.window (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1755:25)
```

I've also tried the code below from [Failed: null value in entry: name=null error while switching Popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477459/failed-null-value-in-entry-name-null-error-while-switching-popup-window) ...

```
function windowCount(count) {
  return function () {
    return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
      return handles.length >= count;
    });
  };
};
browser.wait(windowCount(2), 10000);

browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
  browser.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
  cancelButton.click();
});
```

But that's returning this error:

```
Failed: Wait timed out after 10002ms
TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 10002ms
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2107:17
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: <anonymous wait>
    at scheduleWait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2094:20)
    at ControlFlow.wait (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2408:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `switchTo` method is a wrapper to the selenium-webdriver `switchTo` method. The `switchTo` method returns a `TargetLocator` object and the `TargetLocator` object does not have a `window` method. The correct way to do this is to use the [frame method](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js#L1818).

```
browser.getAllWindowHandles().then((handles) => {
  let newWindowHandle = handles[1];
  browser.switchTo().frame(newWindowHandle).then(() => {
    cancelButton.click();
  });
});
```